# Cactus Comments and SvelteKit with adapter-static and CSR

Tags: sveltekit, client-side-rendering

I added comments, using Cactus Comments, to my website made with SvelteKit. However to do it, I had to disable CSR and rely only on prerendering as I am using adapter-static. However, with CSR, the comments window never shows. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    /**
     * @type {string}
     */
     export let id;
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://latest.cactus.chat/cactus.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://latest.cactus.chat/style.css" type="text/css" />
</svelte:head>

{@html "<div id='comment-section'>"}
{@html "</div>"}
{@html `<script>initComments({node: document.getElementById('comment-section'),defaultHomeserverUrl: 'https://matrix.cactus.chat:8448',serverName: 'cactus.chat',siteName: 'ak55site',commentSectionId: '${id}'});</script>`}
<p>If the comments section doesn't appear, try reloading the page</p>
```

Soon, I am wanting to add a download counter using an API, which will need to have CSR. How do I use CSR and Cactus Comments?

I have tried searching the internet, but there is no information about using Cactus Comments and SvelteKit together

Comment: I fixed it. Don't worry. I use on:load to run initialiseComments after cactus comments has loaded